# Node.js passing a variable into a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello guys can someone pls help me.I am trying to make a simple sign up login site and i can't pass the response into my callback i already tired `bind()` and a global variable.The problem is `res.writeHead()`

```
http.createServer(function (req,res){
var body = '';
if(req.method='POST'){
    req.on('data',function(chunk){
        body+=chunk;
    });

    req.on('end',function(){
        console.log('POSTED: ' + body);
        var content = body.split('&');
        if(content[0].split('=')[0] == 'login')
        {
            connectDB(dbURL,function(){
                User.findOne({
                    'username':content[1].split('=')[1],
                    'password':content[2].split('=')[1]},
                function(err,loginUser){
                    console.log(loginUser);

                    if (loginUser != null)
                    {
                        res.writeHead(301,{Location: './page.html'});
                        res.end();
                    }

                    db.close();
                });
            });
```

Comment: Have you tried using a framework like express.js? Might be easier to use...

Comment: What's the error message you get? I also suggest using express.

Comment: Yeah I know it is easier and I will definitely use express.js but first i want to learn things from scratch.And there is no error msg the program runes normally it just wont redirect to the page.html site

Comment: What about `console.log(loginUser);`?

Comment: That is nothing just a line of code i used for debugging :P I was only using to see if the function found the user.

Comment: So... uhm... what exactly is the problem? what are you trying to do? I don't see any passing of variables into callbacks.

Comment: This should be a login which reads the user from the db and redirect him to the ./page.html site if the users exists the problem is the user exists everything is ok but it wont redirect to the page.html when i put the code above the connectDB function it works only when it is inside the anonymous function it doesn't

Comment: And you get an error? or nothing.

Comment: I get nothing, an error would be good then i would know what happened

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with your the connectDB function. Without knowing where that function is from and how it works it's impossible to answer the question.

Comment: Here is the connectDB 


'function connectDB(URL,cb,res){
 mongoose.connect(URL);
 db.on('error',function(c){
  console.error('Connection error');
 });
 db.once('open',function(c){
  console.log('Connected');

  if(cb) cb();
 });
}'

Comment: And you're getting nothing? No logs or anything?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is

```
if (loginUser != null)
```

did you tried?

```
if (loginUser !== null)
```

Comment: That isn't the problem I get into the if statement I already tested that, it can find the user.

Comment: So you're seeing the `console.log(loginUser)` output? If you're getting inside that `if` then there must be some problem elsewhere in the code, I've just pasted your `res.writeHead...` into something I'm working on and it works. Have you tried using the Mongoose query api instead of a callback? `User.findOne({/*blah*/}).exec().then(/*do stuff*/);`